# Submit button linked to wrong form post

Tags: forms, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have multiple post-forms in my view and my second form keeps hitting the first one.

My form looks like this:

```
<form asp-controller="Mentor" asp-action="DeleteAchievement"  asp-route-id="@item.Id" method="post">
    <button asp-route-id="@item.Id" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
 </form>
```

My controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAchievement(string id)
{
  //delete
}
```

Even without routing the id it still doesn't hit it. It just hits the action of the view.

I inspected the generated html and the formaction is for unknown reasons not correspondent to the form but the submit button is linked to another form post.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="/mentor/achievements/634c650b-0659-4fc3-aea6-3ed2d597acb2">Slet</button>
```

I tried doing as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770618/why-is-asp-route-id-not-working-in-my-form-post/42771467) but with no luck. I also tried typing in the formaction for my button in my razor view but not a solution either. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Not sure if it's the solution but `asp-route id="@item.Id"` should be `asp-route-id="@item.Id"`.

Comment: It was just a typo when I formatted the post here. It is correct in my code. Thanks though

Comment: We aren't talking nested forms right?

Comment: No not even. Just in the same razor view.

Comment: Why do you have `asp-route-id` in your button when its already in the `<form>`. And since the method has `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and your `<form> does not include the token, it would throw an error if if did hit it.

Comment: I did like in the answer to the link in my post but I've tried with and without it makes no difference. Also you're wrong about [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] The token is automatically injected into the view by the FormTagHelper (this is .net core 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `form action` should be in the form not button
2. form needs a hidden input field with `item.Id` as value

`<form asp-controller="Mentor" asp-action="DeleteAchievement" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" asp-for="item.Id" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
     </form>`